# Como faço para pegar um valor Long num EditText e inserir no Firebase?(Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Preciso pegar um valor tipo Long e inserir no Firebase e depois mostra-lo numa ListView. Criei uma classe Pessoa e com os outros atributos consegui inserir e mostrar numa boa. Somente o atributo Long não consigo, dá erro. Estou recebendo os valores pelo Plain Text(EditText)
Minha classe Pessoa está assim:

```
`public class Pessoa {
private String latitude,longitude;
private String uid;
private String cnpj;
private String razao;
private Long  codigo;

public Pessoa() {
}...



public Long getCodigo() {

    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return
            "Código Cliente:" +codigo +"\n"+
            "CNPJ:" +cnpj +"\n"+
            "Razão Social:" +razao +"\n"+
            "Latitude:" +latitude +"\n"+
            "Longitude:" +longitude +"\n"

    ;
}
```

}
`
Aqui está minha MainActivity, podem ver que tento pegar o id do Long e colocar no Firebase e o erro já aparece na linha onde insiro o Long:

> O codigo segue para retornar numa ListView mas não é necessario mostrar o restante, o mesmo erro já está presente nessa parte do codigo

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText cnpj1,razao1, latitude1, longitude1,codigo1;
private ListView list;
private Button botao2;
private DatabaseReference referencia = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

private List<Pessoa> listPessoa = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();
private ArrayAdapter<Pessoa> arrayAdapterPessoa;
Pessoa pessoaSelecionada;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    codigo1 = findViewById(R.id.CodigoCliente);
    cnpj1 = findViewById(R.id.CnpjCliente);
    razao1 = findViewById(R.id.RazaoCliente);
    latitude1 = findViewById(R.id.LatitudeCliente);
    longitude1 = findViewById(R.id.LongitutudeCliente);
    botao2 = findViewById(R.id.buttonCliente);
    list = findViewById(R.id.ListaCliente);



    botao2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
            p.setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

            p.setCnpj(cnpj1.getText().toString());
            p.setRazao(razao1.getText().toString());
            p.setLatitude(latitude1.getText().toString());
            p.setLongitude(longitude1.getText().toString());
            p.setCodigo(Long.parseLong(codigo1.getText().toString()));




            referencia.child("Cliente").child(p.getUid()).setValue(p);











        }
    });
    eventoDatabase1();
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            pessoaSelecionada = (Pessoa) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);


            codigo1.setText(pessoaSelecionada.getCodigo()));// Aqui é onde dá o erro, desse jeito fica a linha em vermelho, se coloco o toString, o app para.

            cnpj1.setText(pessoaSelecionada.getCnpj());
            razao1.setText(pessoaSelecionada.getRazao());
            latitude1.setText(pessoaSelecionada.getLatitude());
            longitude1.setText(pessoaSelecionada.getLongitude());

        }
    });


}
private void eventoDatabase1(){
    referencia.child("Cliente").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            listPessoa.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot objSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Pessoa c = objSnapshot.getValue(Pessoa.class);
                listPessoa.add(c);

            }
            arrayAdapterPessoa = new ArrayAdapter<Pessoa>(MainActivity2.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listPessoa);
            list.setAdapter(arrayAdapterPessoa);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id== R.id.menu_novo){
        Pessoa v = new Pessoa();
        v.setCodigo(Long.parseLong(codigo1.getText().toString()));

        v.setCnpj(cnpj1.getText().toString());
        v.setLatitude(latitude1.getText().toString());
        v.setRazao(razao1.getText().toString());
        v.setLongitude(longitude1.getText().toString());
        v.setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        referencia.child("Cliente").child(v.getUid()).setValue(v);
        limparcampos();
    }else if(id == R.id.menu_atualiza){
        Pessoa v = new Pessoa();
        v.setUid(pessoaSelecionada.getUid());
        v.setCnpj(cnpj1.getText().toString());
        v.setRazao(razao1.getText().toString());
        v.setLatitude(latitude1.getText().toString());
        v.setLongitude(longitude1.getText().toString());
        v.setCodigo(Long.parseLong(codigo1.getText().toString().trim()));
        referencia.child("Cliente").child(v.getUid()).setValue(v);
        limparcampos();
    }else if( id == R.id.menu_deleta){
        Pessoa v = new Pessoa();
        v.setUid(pessoaSelecionada.getUid());
        referencia.child("Cliente").child(v.getUid()).removeValue();
        limparcampos();
    }
    return true;
}

public void limparcampos(){
    codigo1.setText("");
    cnpj1.setText("");
    razao1.setText("");

    latitude1.setText("");
    longitude1.setText("");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vamos olhar o método `setCodigo`:

```java
public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}
```

Veja que ele recebe um `Long` como parâmetro.

Vamos olhar como você está chamando o método `setCodigo`:

```java
p.setCodigo(codigo1.getText().toString());
```

Você está chamando o método `toString()`, portanto você está passando uma `String` para um método que recebe um `Long`, assim o erro. Para corrigir o erro, basta utilizar o método [`Long.parseLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String)):

```java
p.setCodigo(Long.parseLong(codigo1.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: Essa parte deu certo! Estou com um problema no mesmo Long em outro bloco agora, tentei o Long.parseLong e não deu certo. segue abaixo o bloco:
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                pessoaSelecionada = (Pessoa) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                
                codigo1.setText(pessoaSelecionada.getCodigo()); // o erro está aqui
                
                cnpj1.setText(pessoaSelecionada.getCnpj());

Comment: codigo1.setText(pessoaSelecionada.getCodigo().toString());

Comment: Coloquei esse código, compilou sem problemas, quando abro a activity que está esse código, ela fecha do nada. Como se o código estivesse com algum bug. Ai quando altero o atributo Long na classe Pessoa para String e faço igual os outros, dá certo. Somente quando mudo pro Long dá esse problema. Teria alguma coisa a mais que possa ser feito?

Comment: É difícil dizer, talvez possa estar ocorrendo um NullPointerException, como o código de alguma pessoa não sendo definido, por exemplo. Você pode tentar editar sua questão incluindo o código relevante, caso não seja muito grande. Do contrário, você pode utilizar um depurador.

Comment: Incluí o código da minha MainActivity todo, coloquei marcado com // a linha que eu acho que está dando o erro.

Comment: Não consigo ver uma possível causa, sem o stacktrace fica um pouco complicado. Você pode adicionar [esse plugin](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/CrashReporter) ao seu aplicativo que ele mostrará em uma nova tela o erro causado. Por hora, uma possível solução: tente ao invés de codigo1.setText(pessoaSelecionada.getCodigo().toString()) colocar codigo1.setText(Objects.toString(pessoaSelecionada.getCodigo())) e adicionar ao topo do seu arquivo a linha `import java.util.Objects;`.

Comment: Ok, agradeço a atenção e a ajuda. Valeuuu